# Why Androidx is being imported when I didn't take the nessessary dependencies?

Tags: android, androidx

I was using AppCompat library in my android app. Recently I have decided to migrate to AndroidX components. So in my `gradle.properties` I have taken this:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

And Taken the appcompat dependency in `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

But it's strange that I can use lifecycle, viewmodel etc jetpack library without importing any more dependencies there. Is there any hidden feature I don't know which is allowing me to use those libraries? And even when I delete the "`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'`" from the gradle file, it works without any coompile error. Now I am confused, can anyone give me a valid reason of it? I have rebuild, removed cache and even I have restarted my PC several time, but it works. How is this possible? btw my root level build.gradle file has this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"

        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Yes, it gets imported by default, because **appcompat library** depends on it. *(Moreover, architecture components are implemented on SDK components itself even it you use it in your project or not. I.e. ViewModel & Lifecycle libraries)*

Comment: @JeelVankhede Please post it as an Answer, I will mark it as a solution, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, **Architecture components** are integrated in **Android SDK** itself whether you use it or not. That's because it gives you support for *Lifecycle* of `Activity/Fragment` from SDK component out of the box & that's why you're able to see jetpack libraries such as *viewmodel & lifecycle*.

So, importing `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` artifact will resolve it's internal dependecies of viewmodel & lifecycle *(I.e. due to AppCompatActivity and other components depended on it)* and is the reason why you're able to see it.